# Trigger to fetch value from top of the hierarchy, before insert/update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I´m using Oracle 11.

I have to do a trigger which fetch value from PARENT_ID's VALUE -column and place it to CHILD_ID's VALUE column in same table.

```
LEVEL  CHILD_ID   PARENT_ID   VALUE(of PARENT_ID) VALUE(of CHILD_ID)
10     07615461   09479551    111                 'null'  should have 111 from parent_id
20     07776685   07615461    111                 'null'  should have 111 from parent_id
20     08195786   07615461    111                 'null'  should have 111 from parent_id
```

So query for the trigger had to do hierarchically but I dont know how the syntax actually goes.

I have tried something like this but without success

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER value_check

BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table.a

   FOR EACH ROW                             

     BEGIN                                  

      IF :new.VALUE is NULL then            

       :new.VALUE := select b.VALUE,          

       connect_by_root(a.child_id)           

       from table a join table b              

       on a.child_id = b.child_id              

       connect by prior a.child_id = a.parent_id   

       start with a.level = 10;                    

      END IF;                                     

    END;
```

Huge thanks for your effort, help, tips, tricks, everything

---

Maybe I wasnt clear enough, so let´s try again...

I need a trigger which checks VALUE from ID which is highest in hierarchy (level 10) and replicate this VALUE to every other ID´s below it.
For example if ID 07615461 in level 10 has VALUE 111, this VALUE should be copied to every other ID´s below 07615461.
like, ID 07776685 (in level 20) and ID 08195786 (in level 20), each should have same VALUE 111 than ID 07615461 has in level 10.
Does this make any sense?
My matrix propably wasnt good enough, s here´s another try:

Currently:

`LEVEL  CHILD_ID   PARENT_ID   VALUE
10     07615461   09479551    111
20     07776685   07615461    null
20     08195786   07615461    null`

After trigger:

`LEVEL  CHILD_ID   PARENT_ID   VALUE
10     07615461   09479551    111
20     07776685   07615461    111
20     08195786   07615461    111`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you want to do. Sample data you provided doesn't help much. It would be better if you posted what you currently have, what you want to have and rules that make that happen. I don't understand what are those labels - do they belong to the same table? What are their names? Why did you use 111 for all rows - it brings confusion (unless that's what you really have; I doubt that). As of code you wrote: in PL/SQL, SELECT requires an INTO clause, so you'd `select b.value into :new.value`, but - somehow - I don't think it'll help much.

Comment: I edited bit my original question by adding hopefully better matrix from starting point to hoped result.

Comment: Thank you for that; however, I still don't understand how are those CHILD_ID values related. They don't share *anything*; I'd expect them to have the same PARENT_ID, but they do not. Or, if it was a hierarchy (as your UPDATE suggests), there's no way to get from 07615461 to 07776685 nor 08195786. My next question is: why should I update 07776685 CHILD_ID's VALUE to 111? It has nothing to do with CHILD_ID = 07615461. In other words, I don't see any relation between them. The way you put it so far, you'd update any VALUE whose LEVEL is higher than 10.